# bootstrap to display click result without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page that I have it split in half.  The left side will have the text hyperlinks or buttons, and on the right side I need to display the results without page refresh.  I'm hoping that bootstrap has something like this but have not been able to find it.  Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap doesn't provide AJAX calls, it's more for styling your site web.  For this, you need to check the [jQuery AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

**Edit**

Here's a simple example to make AJAX calls.

*index.php* (Basic HTML code)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button id="cats" data-animal="cats" class="btn btn-default">Text on cats</button>
            <button id="dogs" data-animal="dogs" class="btn btn-default">Text on dogs</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="results"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

*script.js* (Script where the AJAX call will be made)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this  = $(this),
            animal = $this.data('animal');

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "getAnimal.php",
            dataType: "html",
            data: { pet : animal },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#results").html('').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

*getAnimal.php* (PHP script called by AJAX)

```
<?php
$animal = $_POST['pet'];

if($animal == "cats") {
   echo "You clicked on cats!";
}
else if($animal == "dogs") {
    echo "You clicked on dogs!";
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm hoping it will not create conflict with bootstrap's jQuery.

Comment: It should not create any problems.  I'm using both quite often :)

Comment: Would you happen to have a sample?  I'm a newbee and trying to find my way around. I mean what needs to go in the left side of the page and what needs to go in right side.

Comment: So, getAnimal.php code will need to be on the right side of the page I want to display the results as well as the script.js  ?   Thanks again Marc

Comment: Actually Bootstrap will do this for you.  I used `<div class="col-md-6">`on 2 differents `<div>` so bootstrap will make they width 50% (left and right column) [Grid documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).  Then, when you click on any of the 2 buttons, I make an AJAX call to `getAnimal.php` to get the information I need then I'm outputting this information in the `<div id="results">`.  I hope it helps a little bit more

Comment: I uploaded the files I used to create this example on [this link](http://www.filedropper.com/ajax_1)

Answer (score 0):

Are these links all in the same domain? If so, it's not too hard to fetch the content at each URL using jQuery's ajax API.

Comment: Yes. They're all in same domain.

Comment: OK, then I have the same advice as Marc-Andre :)